# Idea behind this bit manipulation code to achieve 5/8 of a number?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am working on a problem where I have to computer five eighth (5/8) of a given number using bit operations?

For positive number, I can do pretty easily. Basically, it is `( (x << 2) + x )>> 3`.

However, for negative number it does not seem to work. I looked around the web, and apparently, I have to add a factor of 7, however, I can't quiet see why that would be required?

Comment: The logic is complex and I don't quite get it, but what if you just negated x? `-(( (-x << 2) + -x )>> 3)`, then re-negated the result?

Comment: @dana the logic is just `x * 5 / 8` but with a division that rounds down instead of towards zero

Comment: @harold Could you please elaborate why adding 7 is needed? I can't quiet visualize it?

Answer (score 2):

Division using shifting *rounds towards negative infinity*, while normal C division rounds towards zero.

That is, `-9 / 8 == 1` (i.e., `-1.25` rounded towards zero is `-1`), but `-9 >> 2 == -2` (i.e., ``-1.25` rounded towards negative infinity is -2).

To fix that, *for the specific case of division by 8* you can add 7 in the case of negative numbers to "adjust" the dividend such that the rounding happens as you expect.

---

The entirety of this question assumes your C compiler implements "arithmetic right shifts" for signed right shifts. Pretty much all architecture/compiler combinations do, but it's not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Can you please point out why we add exactly 7 not something else, and how does it help mathematically ? Will be different for different denominator?

Comment: When you divide a negative number `N` using shifting , you can add `N-1` to round towards zero. So `8 - 1 == 7`. You can work though some examples yourself - try `-9, -8 and -7` to test the "boundary" cases. It is similar to how you can "round up" using normal division in C by adding `divisor - 1` to the dividend. @Dude

Comment: You mean towards *negative* infinity though, right? Also some negative signs seem to have disappeared

Comment: @harold - yes exactly, I meant negative inifinty. I added about 3 or 4 negative signs, hopefully that was all of them! Admittedly I had the example as a positive division at first, then realized it should be negative and converted it poorly.

Answer (score 1):

For positive `x`, `x >> 3` and `x / 8` both round toward zero.

For negative `x`, `x >> 3` rounds toward negative infinity, while `x / 8` rounds toward zero. Examples:

```
 -1 >> 3 = -1     -1 / 8 =  0     different
 -2 >> 3 = -1     -2 / 8 =  0     different
 -3 >> 3 = -1     -3 / 8 =  0     different
 -4 >> 3 = -1     -4 / 8 =  0     different
 -5 >> 3 = -1     -5 / 8 =  0     different
 -6 >> 3 = -1     -6 / 8 =  0     different
 -7 >> 3 = -1     -7 / 8 =  0     different
 -8 >> 3 = -1     -8 / 8 = -1     same
 -9 >> 3 = -2     -9 / 8 = -1     different
-10 >> 3 = -2    -10 / 8 = -1     different
-11 >> 3 = -2    -11 / 8 = -1     different
-12 >> 3 = -2    -12 / 8 = -1     different
-13 >> 3 = -2    -13 / 8 = -1     different
-14 >> 3 = -2    -14 / 8 = -1     different
-15 >> 3 = -2    -15 / 8 = -1     different
-16 >> 3 = -2    -16 / 8 = -2     same
-17 >> 3 = -3    -17 / 8 = -2     different
-18 >> 3 = -3    -18 / 8 = -2     different
-19 >> 3 = -3    -19 / 8 = -2     different
```

When the numerator (`x`) is a multiple of the denominator (8), the results are the same. For the other 7/8 of the results, the results are different by 1. This means if we want `>> 3` to behave the same as `/ 8`, we need to change the numerator.

Generally speaking, if you have an integer division operator that rounds down, you can make it round up by adding (denominator - 1) to the numerator. But let's get there in baby steps. Suppose we change the numerator by adding 1:

```
( -1 + 1) >> 3 =  0     -1 / 8 =  0     same
( -2 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -2 / 8 =  0     different
( -3 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -3 / 8 =  0     different
( -4 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -4 / 8 =  0     different
( -5 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -5 / 8 =  0     different
( -6 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -6 / 8 =  0     different
( -7 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -7 / 8 =  0     different
( -8 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -8 / 8 = -1     same
( -9 + 1) >> 3 = -1     -9 / 8 = -1     same
(-10 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -10 / 8 = -1     different
(-11 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -11 / 8 = -1     different
(-12 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -12 / 8 = -1     different
(-13 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -13 / 8 = -1     different
(-14 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -14 / 8 = -1     different
(-15 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -15 / 8 = -1     different
(-16 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -16 / 8 = -2     same
(-17 + 1) >> 3 = -2    -17 / 8 = -2     same
(-18 + 1) >> 3 = -3    -18 / 8 = -2     different
(-19 + 1) >> 3 = -3    -19 / 8 = -2     different
```

Now we have 2/8 of the results matching. Try adding 2:

```
( -1 + 2) >> 3 =  0     -1 / 8 =  0     same
( -2 + 2) >> 3 =  0     -2 / 8 =  0     same
( -3 + 2) >> 3 = -1     -3 / 8 =  0     different
( -4 + 2) >> 3 = -1     -4 / 8 =  0     different
( -5 + 2) >> 3 = -1     -5 / 8 =  0     different
( -6 + 2) >> 3 = -1     -6 / 8 =  0     different
( -7 + 2) >> 3 = -1     -7 / 8 =  0     different
( -8 + 2) >> 3 = -1     -8 / 8 = -1     same
( -9 + 2) >> 3 = -1     -9 / 8 = -1     same
(-10 + 2) >> 3 = -1    -10 / 8 = -1     same
(-11 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -11 / 8 = -1     different
(-12 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -12 / 8 = -1     different
(-13 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -13 / 8 = -1     different
(-14 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -14 / 8 = -1     different
(-15 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -15 / 8 = -1     different
(-16 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -16 / 8 = -2     same
(-17 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -17 / 8 = -2     same
(-18 + 2) >> 3 = -2    -18 / 8 = -2     same
(-19 + 2) >> 3 = -3    -19 / 8 = -2     different
```

Apparently, if we compute `(x + i) >> 3`, (i+1)/8 of the results match. So to make all of the results match, we solve (i+1)/8 = 1 for i, getting i = 7. And here's what we get if we add 7 to the numerator:

```
( -1 + 7) >> 3 =  0     -1 / 8 =  0     same
( -2 + 7) >> 3 =  0     -2 / 8 =  0     same
( -3 + 7) >> 3 =  0     -3 / 8 =  0     same
( -4 + 7) >> 3 =  0     -4 / 8 =  0     same
( -5 + 7) >> 3 =  0     -5 / 8 =  0     same
( -6 + 7) >> 3 =  0     -6 / 8 =  0     same
( -7 + 7) >> 3 =  0     -7 / 8 =  0     same
( -8 + 7) >> 3 = -1     -8 / 8 = -1     same
( -9 + 7) >> 3 = -1     -9 / 8 = -1     same
(-10 + 7) >> 3 = -1    -10 / 8 = -1     same
(-11 + 7) >> 3 = -1    -11 / 8 = -1     same
(-12 + 7) >> 3 = -1    -12 / 8 = -1     same
(-13 + 7) >> 3 = -1    -13 / 8 = -1     same
(-14 + 7) >> 3 = -1    -14 / 8 = -1     same
(-15 + 7) >> 3 = -1    -15 / 8 = -1     same
(-16 + 7) >> 3 = -2    -16 / 8 = -2     same
(-17 + 7) >> 3 = -2    -17 / 8 = -2     same
(-18 + 7) >> 3 = -2    -18 / 8 = -2     same
(-19 + 7) >> 3 = -2    -19 / 8 = -2     same
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it more visual,

Take the number, say, -42 (which is not a multiple of 5, but whatever)

```
‭11010110
```

Put a radix point 3 places from the right (this divides by 8)

```
11010.110 = -5.25
```

How to round up: add ones to all fraction bits (meaning that iff those are not all zero, the addition will carry into the integer part), so 0.111, then chop:

```
11010.110
    0.111     = 7/8
--------- +
11011.101     = -4.375
chop:
11011.000     = -5
```

To convert to a normal integer, shift until the radix point is just before the least significant bit:

```
11011.000 >>s 3 =
11111011.          = still -5, but in normal integer format
```

In the code you just put the radix point in virtually (so do nothing, but then proceed as if it is there) and fractions are implicit (so 7/8 is written as 7). And the chop is unnecessary since the right shift throws those bits out anyway. All that's left is add 7, then shift.